# Attempt to invoke virtual method '...' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I getting the "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null "
error in some devices:

Stack Trace:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.facebook.misstest/com.facebook.misstest.LoveMeterResultActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3254)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3350)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 (ActivityThread.java:222)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1795)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7229)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run       
(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method    'java.lang.String[] android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
com.facebook.misstest.LoveMeterResultActivity.onCreate      
(LoveMeterResultActivity.java:133)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6876)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1135)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3207)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3350)
```

Here is the code which is send data to the next activity:

```
            //send this result to LoveMeterResultActivity
            final Bundle basket = new Bundle();
            basket.putStringArray("key", loveData);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoveMeterActivity.this, LoveMeterResultActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(basket);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: loveData is null fill it with Love

Comment: what i should do in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check intent is null or not before you get data

```
Intent intent=this.getIntent();
if(intent !=null){
       // do something you want
    }
```

example

In ClassA:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassB);
String[] myStrings = new String[] {"test", "test2"};
intent.putExtra("strings", myStrings);
startActivity(intent);
```

In ClassB:

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
     if(intent !=null){
          String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
      }
```

Comment: i think it can be work, but i'm going to test in different devices before accept the awnser

Comment: @ahsen mughal as your wish :))